# Select Single Node Value from XML using F#

Tags: xml, f#

I have a very simple xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>SomeSoftware</id>
        <title>Some Software</title>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

From this file I would like to extract the value of the version node, using F#.

```ml
let xmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
let namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
namespaces.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd");
xmlDocument.Load "software.nuspec"

let node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode "/package/metadata/version" :?> XmlElement
if node = null then
  printfn "unable to find version"
else
  printfn "%s" node.Value
```

I have tried a few variations on this, but I don't seem to be able to print the version to my console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work - I added the `ns:` prefix to the XPath and also added the XML namespace manager as another argument. I also changed your code to access `InnerText` rather than `Value` of the XML element:

```
let node =  
  xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode
    ("/ns:package/ns:metadata/ns:version", namespaces) :?> XmlElement
if node = null then
  printfn "unable to find version"
else
  printfn "%s" node.InnerText
```

Although, if you wanted to make this nicer, you could use the [XML type provider from F# Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) which makes it much nicer - assuming `software.nuspec` is in the current directory, you can write:

```
type NuSpec = XmlProvider<"software.nuspec">
NuSpec.Load("software.nuspec").Metadata.Version
```

Comment: Was just going to suggest you add the XML type provider as an additional suggestion to your answer.  For any more complicated cases, it'll certainly make the OP's life a lot easier.

Comment: The xml type provider is pretty nice, I've gone for that.